# uMongo get random document from collection

Tags: python, mongodb, umongo

I'm currently learning MongoDb and creating an app on `python`. I need to select one random document from `user` collection using uMongo, I have tried `aggregate` but it says that umongo have no this function. How can i do that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try: `user.collection.aggregate(...)`. [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html) returns random document

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to use the aggregation framework.

To do so, you must circumvent umongo to call the underlying driver (e.g. pymongo) directly.